# SELECT from many different tables and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I need to combine a few different columns from different tables.
These are listed here. I just can't seem to get the syntax right. I'm a beginner so be patient with me!

The tables are 'report', 'mission' and 'hist_unit'
and the following values are the same

```
mission.id = report.mission_id
hist_unit.id = report.deployed_unit_id
```

Tried something along these lines

```
    SELECT
mission_id AS mission_id,
deployed_unit_id AS depl_unit_id,
accepted AS accepted,
character_id AS character_id,
pilot_status AS pilot_status
FROM report

id AS depl_unit_id
faction AS faction
FROM hist_unit

mission.id AS mission_id
hist_date AS hist_date
FROM mission
```

What I want this query to do is putting together the columns shown above  and checking that the values shown at the top correspond to each other.
Then I want it to show me only the lines where faction = 3 and accepted = 1. 
Then I want it to show me only the entries

```
WHERE hist_date BETWEEN '1941-11-15 00:00:00.000' AND '1942-04-15 23:59:59:999'
```

Output should be something like this

```
mission_id,depl_unit_id,faction,character_id,pilot_status,accepted,hist_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 SELECT r.id                   AS report_id
      , r.mission_id           AS mission_id
      , r.deployed_unit_id     AS depl_unit_id
      , r.accepted             AS accepted
      , r.character_id         AS character_id
      , r.pilot_status         AS pilot_status

      , h.id                   AS h_depl_unit_id
      , h.faction              AS faction

      , m.id                   AS m_mission_id

   FROM report r

   JOIN hist_unit h
     ON h.id = r.deployed_unit_id

   JOIN mission m
     ON m.id  = r.mission_id

 WHERE h.hist_date  >= '1941-11-15' 
   AND h.hist_date  <  '1942-04-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND h.faction    =  3
   AND r.accepted   =  1

 ORDER 
    BY r.id
     , r.mission_id
```

---

After the SELECT keyword, list all of the expressions to be returned.

The `FROM` clause references the tables. Multiple tables should be separated by JOIN keyword, and then either an `ON` clause. (INNER keyword is not required; CROSS keyword is not required, but can be included when there is no join condition, as an aid to the future reader; outer joins require addition of `LEFT` (or `RIGHT` keyword).

Consider assigning an alias to each table reference.

**Qualify *all* column references** with the assigned table alias (or the table name, if an alias is not assigned.)

When the `AS column_name` is omitted for a column in the SELECT list, the column name is used.  For example, we could omit `AS accepted` and that fourth column would still have the name accepted.

Avoid returning multiple columns with the sane name. It's not illegal to do that, but consider modifying the column aliases (column names in the resultset) to be unique. i.e. one of the `depl_unit_id` columns can be renamed.

---

When comparing date time values in ranges, strongly consider using `>=` and `<` comparisons.  Don't try to muck with less than or equal to `23:59:59.999` ... what if precision is microseconds, we are leaving a small gap.  Let's avoid the gap, and just do a "less than" midnight of the next day, the first datetime value we want to exclude. (Yes, we have to specify the column name / expression twice, once for each comparison, because there is not `BETWEEN_GE_LT` comparison operator that substitutes a "less than" comparison for the "less than or equal to" comparison of the `BETWEEN` operator. That's a small price to pay for a more explicitly accurate representation of what we are attempting to achieve.